# Proving $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational: why $ q = p - \frac{p^2 -2}{p+2}$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-number-theory, proof-explanation, irrational-numbers

I've just begun self-studying Rubin's Principals of Mathematical Analysis.

I'm having difficulty understanding a specific line in example 1.1 (proving $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational). Specifically, I'm trying to understand how they arrive at the following:

$ q = p - \frac{p^2 -2}{p+2}$

Here is the proof up to that point:

Let A be the set of all positive rationals p such that $p^2 < 2$ and let B consist of all positive rationals p such that $p^2 > 2$. We shall show that A contains no largest number and B contains no smallest number.

More explicitly, for every p in A we can find a rational q in A such that $p < q$, and for every p in B we can find a rational q in B such that $q < p$.

Any help would be much appreciated.